# Do high speed trains use ventilation and filtration systems similar to aircraft?

Tags: hvac, rail, transportation, air-quality

[This](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/should-i-cancel-my-flight-will-recirculated-air-on-a-plane-spread-coronavirus-heres-what-you-need-to-know-before-traveling-2020-03-06) article discusses the ventilation and filtration in aircraft:

> Ventilation rates provide a total change of air 20 to 30 times per
>   hour. Most modern aircraft have recirculation systems, which recycle
>   up to 50% of cabin air. The recirculated air is usually passed through
>   HEPA (high-efficiency particulate air) filters, of the type used in
>   hospital operating theatres and intensive care units, which trap dust
>   particles, bacteria, fungi and viruses.

Does ventilation and filtration in high speed trains typically work the same way, including with similar air renewal intervals, recycling rates, filtration quality?

Comment: Hmm most aircraft ventilation is bleed off from the first compressor stage of the engine afaik

Comment: An airplane has different design requirements.  First of all, the airplane system must pressurize the aircraft.  This means the energy to bring in air is increase.  Second, as @SolarMike says, pulling in the air affects engine efficiency.  A train will just need blowers like a car.